# multiple spinner controlling each other

Tags: android, spinner

i have tried to search for this and the best soultion i can find is notifyDataSetChange() but that doesn't seem to work.

I have 4 spinners looking up bible chapters and verses.
spinner 1 lists books of bible, genesis...revelations
spinner 2 chapters
spinner 3 start verse
spinner 4 end verse

spinner1.onItemSelectedListener() ItemSelected() it populates spinner2 with correct number of chapters

spinner2.onItemSelectedListener() ItemSelected() it populates spinner3 with correct number of verses

spinner3.onItemSelectedListener() ItemSelected() it populates spinner4 with correct number of verses beginning with value of spinner3

what i am trying to do is store a series of verse and flip through them like flip cards. so store gen 1:1 then store lev 2:6-7 then store rev 22:17....

all this seems to be working, where it breaks is when i click my previous/next button, it gets the right data and sets the spinenrs but then the spinners execute their onItemSelectedListener action.

```
nextVerseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(currentCardBeingViewed < sermon.getNumberOfSVE()){
                loadSermonCard(sermon.getSVE(currentCardBeingViewed));
                currentCardBeingViewed++;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End of Sermon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });

private void loadSermonCard(SermonVerseExplain sve){
     sets all 4 spinners according to data stored in sve.
}
```

after loadSermonCard() executes it then calls the onItemSelectedListener to all the spinners and it defaults first different one in series.

so if the current viewed verse is genesis 1:1-1 and i want to go to gen 1:2-4 it will display gen 1:2-2.

however if going from gen 1:1-1 to Exo 2:9-10 it will display Exo 1:1-1.

is there a way to manually tell the spinner to change on command so that it does it inside the loadSermonCard() rather than waiting for the function to end, i tried notify(). it seems as if it sees the change in the function and puts it in cue waiting for the loadSermonCard() to end. then after that begins to execute the listeners.

Comment: i have solved this problem. not sure if it is the best way and this is the second time this situation has occured.

asynctask failed. even with the ability to send UI change requests through either the progressUpdate method or the postexexute method this proved to be incompatible with the situation i was having of not being able to have a spinner values change. basically i need to be able to change spinner2 then move it to its location which will then change spinner3 and move down the line.

ultimately i just had ot use a boolean to keep it from updating while i was doing the other updates.